# Getting error running GRASS GIS 7.6.1

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, error

Here is the error notice I receive after starting GRASS GIS 7.6. I am not sure what is the source of these errors. I had reinstalled the application but it didn't fixed these errors.

What are possible remedial measures?

[image: GRASS ERROR WINDOW]

and here are gisrc file contents after installation.

[image]

Comment: In line 4 of your error message is an "invalid line" entry: can you please open the file and report that 4th line here by editing your question and adding that?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: GISDBASE is set to the wrong path for whatever reason. It should point to your "grassdata" directory. Perhaps simply delete .grassrc76 and start GRASS GIS to re-generate it properly

Comment: I had properly uninstalled and thereafter reinstalled GRASS but issue is still unresolved. Alternatively, deleted .grassrc76 but unable to get rid of this issue.

Comment: This is to update that I have solved this problem by removing "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7" folder. The program successfully launched thereafter.